# How to define the SAP mandant/client number in an SAPUI5 application running inside Eclipse WebApp preview?

Tags: sapui5, sap-basis, netweaver

With the Eclipse development tools for SAPUI5 it is possible to run a SAPUI5 app in WebApp preview mode. It's working fine expect one point.

The client data used in OData service is always "100" by default.
I assume the used client is the one used for repository setup.

But for testing I have to use a different client (200) because of maintained test data.

Since SAPUI5 1.26.9 and corresponding development tools it seems to work, defining a default client at SAP NetWeaver Gateway but after an upgrade to 1.28.x most of the time client 100 is used.

Now I am searching the documentation for that problem but can't find anything. One problem of course would be to that the search term "client" will not help at all.

I would also aviod to hard code any client number somewhere because at the real system the logged in client will be used automatically.

But in the WebApp preview I will not be asked for a client.

Maybe this is the wrong place to ask this question? In that case I will delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have a parameter in the URL and link that to retrieving your serviceUrl? 

Maybe you can have a URL parameter and based on that you can 2 service URL's one with hard-coded value of client 200 and other without anything.
You can retrieve the parameter:

```
jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("test-mode") === "true";
```

To hard code the client in OData service definition:

```
var sUrl = "proxy/protocol/server:port/pathToService?sap-client=600";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sUrl,true)
```

Comment: Is there a way to hard code the client in OData service definition? Have not found how?

Comment: var sUrl = "proxy/protocol/server:port/pathToService?sap-client=600";
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sUrl,true);
****i am using a default proxy servlet to get over the Cross Origin Issue****

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `sap-client` `GET`-parameter. This one will be passed to your application automatically when you used the SAP Portal or SAPGUI.

`ODataModel` passes it to data-service with its own.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your model object, you can pass some header variables to 'point' to the right sap client.

```
    // Set the client header variable
    var oHeaders = {'sap-client': '120'};
    var bCSRF = "true";
    var oModel = sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(serviceURL, true, "user", "pass", oHeaders, bCSRF, false, false, "", false);
    sap.ui.getCore().getModel(oModel, 'gAppModel')
```

You can test which header variables you need using a REST client like Postman.

The details of the OData constructor can be found in the API - [UI5 OData Model](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#constructor)